# Particle system not rendering, emitter rendering see-through

Tags: rendering, particles, fire

[image][image]I need to motion track a fireplace to some footage. Everything looks fine in the render preview, and even in the viewport, however the actual file that renders doesn't have a fire, and the emitter is see through looking.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The photos are of the render itself, and the render preview.

Comment: Can you post your material setup for the fire domain in your original message. Most of the case the material was not setup correctly

Comment: Second thought is to check on how your render layers are configured. Can you please attach your blend file?

Comment: I added the material setup (I think?) but i couldnt figure out how to add the .blend.

Comment: Please show the nodes you are using in the compositor

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but are the nodes not what i just added? The very first picture?

Comment: No, you added the nodes for the fire material, not the compositor. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC9fZ.png

Comment: Alrighty, i believe i added it now.

Comment: Thank worked! Thanks a lot for your help! Aside from looking cheesy, everything looks great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the rendered layer's image on top of the background plate using Alpha Over:

[image]